# Exception in ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

```
public static int getMin(int[] arr, int min,int max,int a){
    Integer[] test = Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
    List<Integer> list =null;
    list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(test));
    list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(0));
    min = Collections.min(list);
    max = Collections.max(list);

    if(a == 0) {
        return min;
    } else {
        return max;
    }
}
```

List item

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:862)
    at java.util.Collections.min(Collections.java:596)
    at Solution.getMin(Solution.java:47)
```

What is the reason for this exception?

Comment: How many non-`0` elements does your list have?

Comment: it depends on input, and for that question inputs are given on runtime

Comment: As a side note, this is a horribly inefficient way to get the minimum or maximum from an array. Your very first line does already contain a Stream operation, so why not let the Stream return the intended result in the first place: `IntStream is = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(i -> i != 0); OptionalInt result = a == 0? is.min(): is.max();` Then, you have to decide what to do if the result is empty, e.g. `return result.orElse(0);`

Answer (score 1):

## Empty collection

The Javadoc for [`Collections.min`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#min(java.util.Collection)) states that passing an empty collection will throw a [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html).

Add a test for [`List::isEmpty`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#isEmpty()) before checking the minimum and maximum.

Answer (score 1):

You passed an array that contains only zeros. And this line of code removes all zero elements `list.removeAll(Collections.singleton(0));`. After this, the list has size zero - no any elements in it.

---

Here is an example to reproduce the exception

```
private static void getMin() {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Collections.min(list);
}
```